# Why #:crux.db{:id "a"} = {:crux.db/id "a"} in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I was trying to run this script in repl,

```
(clojure.set/rename-keys {:id  "faeb2d4a-2415-423e-bf65-9266ae4c3326"}
                 {:id :crux.db/id})
```

it returns
`#:crux.db{:id "faeb2d4a-2415-423e-bf65-9266ae4c3326"}`
instead of `{:crux.db/id "faeb2d4a-2415-423e-bf65-9266ae4c3326"}`

I thought there is something wrong, but the data is actually correct

```
(:crux.db/id #:crux.db{:id "faeb2d4a-2415-423e-bf65-9266ae4c3326"})
=> "faeb2d4a-2415-423e-bf65-9266ae4c3326"

(= #:crux.db{:id "faeb2d4a-2415-423e-bf65-9266ae4c3326"} {:crux.db/id "faeb2d4a-2415-423e-bf65-9266ae4c3326"})
=> true
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_maps which explains the "Map namespace syntax".

```
#:foo{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} ; shorthand for {:foo/a 1 :foo/b 2 :foo/c 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a shorthand, to save space if many keys in the map have the same namespace.

```
  (let [some-map {:crux.db/name    "Joe Smith"
                  :crux.db/address "123 Foo Bar Lane"
                  :crux.db/phone   "666.555.1234"
                  :crux.db/age     64}]
```

then `some-map` looks like:

```
#:crux.db{:name "Joe Smith",
          :address "123 Foo Bar Lane",
          :phone "666.555.1234",
          :age 69}
```